# netlify deploy doesnt show one of the pages

Tags: reactjs, react-native, deployment, netlify, webdeploy

I uploaded my react portfolio in netlify the home page works normally however when I click on About page it says Page not found.

In the local host it navigates as expected, I still checked the name of the file everywhere is About.

how can I fix this?